# using possessive apostrophe with country names

Tags: possessives

Why is it so that it is more correct to say

> In India, Independence Day is not on August 14th.

instead of

> India's Independence Day is not on August 14th.

?

Is it because the usage of possessive apostrophe with country names is more suitable for some physical objects (India's capital, India's forests, India's population, etc.) rather than some concepts (customs, events, time periods, etc.) ?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that it is incorrect to use the possessive in this case?  One might prefer not to say "Egypt's Christmas is not on the 25th December" because Christmas does not belong exclusively to Egypt, However India's Independence day definitely belongs to India.

Comment: @JavaLatte - My son's English teacher made that correction in his test paper, except it was not India and Independence day, but Canada and Father's day.

Comment: That explains it. Father's day doesn't belong exclusively to Canada. Using the possessive isn't wrong, but the "In Canada" is preferable. Compare these two NGRAM graphs: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=India%27s+independence+day%2C+Indepence+day+in+india&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIndia%20%27s%20independence%20day%3B%2Cc0 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Russia%27s+christmas%2C+Christmas+in+Russia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CChristmas%20in%20Russia%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding

Comment: @JavaLatte - Do you have to?

Comment: do I have to..... what?